# Book library application

Tags: windows, ios, ebooks, collection-manager

I need a library application for iOS capable to:

1. sync book files with my PC (Windows)
2. search and list files by authors, names, custom tags
3. view files using a book reader app (or support viewing FictionBook/.fb2 and EPUB files by itself)

Any advice?

Comment: Will your library only contain ebooks, or also normal books (which you won't be able to read, of course)?

Comment: @nidunc, fb2 and epub (zipped), and a few PDF and DJVU. But last 2 are not absolutely necessary to support.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at **[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com)** (for your PC)

- freeware (opensource) and cross-platform
- powerful and configurable e-books database
- custom database fields
- automatic metadata downloading from Amazon, Google Books, ISBN.org and other sources
- compatible with many readers
- web interface (only to view and download books)
- supports many formats (even multiple formats for the same book)
- editor for some formats (epub)
- export database to different formats (CSV, BibTeX and others)

[image]
Screenshot from [calibre-ebook.org](http://calibre-ebook.com/demo#screenshots)

On your iOS device you could use **[Marvin](http://marvinapp.com/) Reader** and the [MarvinXD](http://blog.marvinapp.com/post/61116544554) Calibre plugin:

- add/delete Calibre database books from Marvin
- annotate books
- view reading progress

Comment: I was going to suggest that but I *think* User626528 is looking for an app for their idevice rather than for their computer.

Comment: I'd prefer software running on my device.

Comment: Also, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_iOS_e-book_reader_software#Supported_File_Formats), Marvin only supports `.epub` ebooks, and not `.fb2` (but maybe that has changed since)

Comment: Is Calibre lightweight?