# Cross-platform ebook collection

Tags: document-management, ebooks

I am searching for a native windows application for book management. The following items are required:

**Compatibility**

1. Must support PD and MOBI as the base, plus any additional
2. Be able to auto-categorise books by author, genre and age

The following options are what I would like in an ideal solution:

**Usability**

2. Should allow custom filters to be applied to the book for user
3. Should allow user comments on books
4. Preferably able to rank book rating with some database

**Ideal features**

5. Mark pages where you are at when reading
6. Allow you to highlight terms/phrases for later review
7. Have ability to edit the font type of the book natively

The process I would like to be able to complete are as follows:

1. Download `networking.pdf` from some website and add to my library

   2. Create custom filters based on `Author` or `Category`
   3. Create custom tags for the book such as `how-to` or `code guides`
   4. Create custom rating of the book

Once all the management has been marked on the windows device, I would like to sync this data to an iPhone to allow me to read on the road.

Refer to the following screenshots for [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/):

It has been quite some time since I have used Calibre (and this was on Linux). Calibre is able to support multiple file types (and converts), custom tagging and also, shared content.

In the initial install of `Calibre eBook Management for Windows` you are prompted to select a device you would like to share books with:

[image: Device Type]

Furthermore, you are then able to configure content sharing to an iPhone via the initial install:

[image: Content Sharing to iPhone]

Lastly you are then able to `Connect to iTunes` to share your media:

[image: Sharing Content to iPhone]

This allows me to also purchase my books in a centralised store, which will aide greatly.

Is anyone aware of an iOS (iPhone) application to pair with this?

Comment: Are you looking for only ebook solutions or only paper book solutions? I see you've tagged it ebook, but please clarify if either type is out of the equation.

Comment: @holroy The question has been updated.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/)? See: [Ebook Management Programs for Windows 8/8.1](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14608/185) / [Literature (PDF) management for institutes](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10438/185) / [Looking for a book library application](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/5600/185) / [our search engine on "calibre"](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=calibre). Cross-platform (Python), supports a variety of book formats incl. reader/converter.

Comment: @Izzy this was my first thought. However I cannot use this on iOS. Can you pleas convert your comment to an answer with a possible iOS partner?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot name an iOS partner – and I cannot say whether/how Calibre meets *all* your requirements (U2 missing, and all of the "ideal" ones) – so I'd not meet our quality standards unless you say those missing parts are "optional" :) To fill the gaps: would "companion apps" for the mobile devices be acceptable, even if they were just book readers, thus permitting only reading/annotations, but not editing your catalog?

Comment: @Izzy Please see my updated question. Your comment is now a valid answer! Please include any well known iOS counterparts you may have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main question you've already answered yourself: **[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/)** is the central place to manage your collection of books. With this application, you can:

- manage your books and their Metadata
- edit your books (if necessary)
- tag them for categorization
- convert them to the formats you might need

*Calibre* is cross-platform, so if one day you want to switch to a different OS, you can take its database along – no work lost, no big migration to be done.

*Calibre* also comes with a build-in web server to be accessed remotely. You will be able accessing your collection

- by author
- by book title
- by tags
- by search (keywords etc.)

Now remains the client-part. For Android, I can point you to my list of [eBook Readers](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/reading_ebookreaders), and name my favorite candidate: **[Moon+ Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreader)**. This app comes with several network libraries pre-configured, and is able to interface with *Calibre* – simply configure your *Calibre* server with it, and you have access to all your books. *Moon+* understands a huge amount of formats (including EPUB, MOBI, PDF, and many more). It features bookmarks as well as annotations; with PDF, those annotations (and highlights, markings, etc.) are even stored directly into the document – in addition to its own database for faster access, with other formats those go to its database only.

iOS is not my area of expertise, but the favorite app there IMHO is **[Stanza](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=284956128&mt=8)**. Like *Moon+*, it supports a wide range of formats, and has lots of customizable features. As I see [my eBook server](http://ebooks.qumran.org/) quite frequented by the Stanza user-agent, it should be safe assuming *Stanza* can be used with *Calibre* as well (same technology behind). Details on that can be found e.g. [with a Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=stanza+calibre), a quick glance confirming the fact.

Comment: Calibre does not seem to support highlighting, right?

Comment: The reader, or the converter, @NicolasRaoul? The reader does not. But if your book-to-create is styled with highlighing, of course that's supported :)

Comment: I was referring to the question's optional feature "Allow you to highlight terms/phrases for later review".

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Ah – then the answer is "no", not with the integrated reader (unless that was added recently; I'm not running the latest version at the moment).

Comment: You might want to add the info explicitly, addressing each requirement directly ^^

Comment: @NicolasRaoul not if I'm not sure if a more recent version hasn't already added that. I can only speak of the version I'm using. Updates might bring new features.

Comment: I use Calibre with Moon Reader for the highlight. This discussion seems old, I don't know if it's still relevant: https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=247734